# Emulator showing black screen on android studio

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, ide, haxm

I am trying to run emulator on android studio. The ide shows the message 
-netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22
creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:792
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

I can't figure what the problem is. What should I do.

Comment: Which OS is your system running? Does your system support Intel virtualization?

Comment: You can use Visual Studios stand alone emulator with android studio: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx 

At least in the meantime. Sometimes deleting an emulator environment and remaking it fixes things when it gets out of whack as well. Which version of android are you trying to emulate? I had most success with 4.x

Comment: @Malwinder I am running windows 10. Yes it supports virtualization.

Comment: @hellyale I was trying to emulate android 5. I have done the deleting and remaking emulator but it didn't fix anything.