# Android x86 emulator launches not responding on windows 10

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I'm running the latest Android Studio 1.4.1, and when I launch an android-x86 (or x64) virtual device, it doesn't launch correctly. The Emulator window appears with the device frame, but the internal "screen" part is all black, then windows reports the emulator window as not responding.

My question looks somewhat similar to [Emulator showing black screen on android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32303436/234) which is currently un-answered

The log from android studio is:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_23
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 576716800
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7040
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 2200
    Label: 
    Blocks: 140800
    Block groups: 5
    Reserved block group size: 39
Created filesystem with 11/35200 inodes and 4536/140800 blocks
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:1152
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 57 114 471 783
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_ga.c:138: curl_easy_perform() failed with code 7 (Error)
emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_ga.c:145: Got HTTP response code 0
```

After this point nothing happens. 
I have Intel HAXM installed and it reports it's all ok.

I previously had Hyper-V installed but disabled (you can't run HAXM and Hyper-V at the same time) - I uninstalled it and it didn't make any difference

Is there anything I can do to further troubleshoot the issue?